# Stored procedure returns int value when the TSQL have full text search property

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, c#-2.0

I have to use `CONTAINS` (full text search) in my stored procedure's query. So when I bind this stored procedure into my application through Entity Framework it returns an `int` value instead of a list of object.

EX:

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTableData]
    (@UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Column1, Column2 
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE Id = @UserId AND CONTAINS(Column1,'test')
END
```

Actual result:

```
public virtual int GetTableData(Nullable<System.Guid> userId)
{
     var userIdParameter = userId.HasValue ?
                    new ObjectParameter("UserId", userId) :
                    new ObjectParameter("UserId", typeof(System.Guid));

     return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetTableData_Result>("GetTableData", userIdParameter );
 }
```

Expected result:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<GetTableData_Result> GetTableData(Nullable<System.Guid> userId)
{
    var userIdParameter = userId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("UserId", userId) :
                new ObjectParameter("UserId", typeof(System.Guid));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetTableData_Result>("GetTableData", userIdParameter );
}
```

If I remove `AND CONTAINS(Column1,'test')` condition, it's working perfectly and gives the expected result.

I also tried with `SET FMTONLY OFF` options. That also not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Need to add any property or any other things in stored procedure?

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create fulltext catalog on your table column.

here is reference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: I already created full text catalog and full text index for table fields.

Comment: try to run your procedure in sql management studio and post output

Comment: I get exact output while I'm running that procedure in my SQL management studio. There was problem when I bind that procedure into my application through entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your stored procedure:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 
FROM TABLE1 AS t1
WHERE Id = @UserId
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS c1
        FROM TABLE1 AS t2
        WHERE (contains(t2.Column1,'test')) AND (t1.Id = t2.Id)
    )
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. But if we use inner query, it will affect query performance. Is there any other ways?

Comment: Well, it's the one way that works for our project. If you have proper indexes it must work fine. Unfortunately, I dont know any other way.. exept of not using full-text search with Entity Framework.

Comment: @LTAravindh so did you find a workaround for your situation?